# How can an SVN::Error callback identify the context from which it was called?

Tags: perl, svn, client

I've written some fairly extensive Perl modules and scripts using the Perl bindings [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SVN::Client) etc. Since the calls to SVN::Client are all deep in a module, I have overridden the default error handling.

So far I have done so by setting

```
$SVN::Error::handler = undef;
```

[as described in the docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SVN::Core#svn_error_t_-_SVN::Error), but this makes the individual calls a bit messy because you have to remember to make each call to `SVN::Client` in list context and test the first value for errors.

I would like to switch to using an error handler I would write; but `$SVN::Error::handler` is global, so I can't see any way that my callback can determine where the error came from, and what object to set an error code in.

I wondered if I could use a pool for this purpose: so far I have ignored pools as irrelevant to working in Perl, but if I call a `SVN::Client` method with a pool I have created, will any [SVN::Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SVN::Error) object be created in the same pool?

Has anybody any knowledge or experience which bears on this?

Comment: May you should take a look at SVK which is completeley writting in Perl with SVN bindings...may be you find some examples in there...
http://search.cpan.org/~clkao/SVK-v2.2.3/lib/SVK.pm

Comment: BTW: the relationship to SVN 1.4.6 is a little bit out of date of Alien-SVN...Another question is comming up to my mind. What is the purpose of implementing in Perl with Bindings? Why not parsing the output of SVN command line client?

Comment: I'm not actually using Alien-SVN, I'm using the bindings that came with SVN 1.6: it's just easier to find the perldoc in Alien-SVN. 

As for why to use the API: why do we ever use an API? The returns from API functions are defined: the messages from a command line tool are usually not.

Comment: @Colin why aren't they defined? Of course they are...or in which circumstances they aren't ?

Comment: Why would you bother specifying exactly which messages your command-line tool output in particular circumstances, and bind yourself to that when you issue a new version? It's pointless. The whole purpose of an API is to provide a defined interface to some tool - forking to call a command line is daft, if there is any alternative.

Comment: What do you want to do when an error happens? Just set a flag in an object that you'll look at later (at the end of the set of operations, before returning to the caller) and continue, or halt everything straight away and return to the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going to assume the issue is that (a) you want to set a flag in some object when an error occurs, and then check the flag later at the end of all operations, and (b) that your error handler (in a global variable) needs some way to know which object to touch. You can achieve this using a closure, something like the following:

```
#
# This part is the library that implements error handling a bit like
# SVN::Client
#
sub default_error_handler {
  croak "An error occurred: $_[0]";
}

our $global_error_handler = \&default_error_handler;

sub library_function_that_might_fail {
  &$global_error_handler("Guess what - it failed!");
}

#
# This part is the function that wants to detect an error
#
sub do_lots_of_stuff {
  my $error = undef; # No errors so far!

  local($global_error_handler) = sub { $error = $_[0]; };

  library_function_that_might_fail();
  library_function_that_might_fail();
  library_function_that_might_fail();

  if ($error) {
    print "There was an error: $error\n";
  }
}


#
# Main program
#
do_lots_of_stuff();
```

The key is that when, in `do_lots_of_stuff()`, we set the error handler to an anonymous sub, that sub continues to have access to the local variables of the function that created it - so it can modify `$error` to signal that an error occurred.

Comment: Thanks. I asked the question quite a while ago, and have moved on somewhat; but when I go back to this project I'll consider this suggestion. Its sounds like just what I wanted.